# Using specific data frame in Python

Tags: python

so I have a huge table with 4 columns, and the thing is I have to use data from 2nd and 3rd columns, but only if the data in 1st column has values between A and B. Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: what did you try ? Show your code and full error message.

Comment: you can try: df[df.col_1.between(A, B)][['col_2', 'col_3]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but to filter the dataframe for rows that have values between A and B in Column1 you could to this:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['Col1'] > A) & (df['Col1'] < B)]
```